# Stop users from connecting if a WiFi is full

Tags: wireless-networking

I am using a TP-WR841N with the mash-net Freifunk-gluon firmware.
This model seems to be able to handle only around 20 clients, if there are more trying to connect to the network, they seem to block the whole router and no client (also the ones already connected) can use the Internet properly any more.
I thiny the best would be if the network becomes invisible somehow, once there are connected enough routers.

How can I limit the number of users that can try to connect to 20?

Comment: From where are the clients getting IP addresses?  Do you have a separate DHCP server or are you issuing IPs straight from the wireless router?

Comment: Separate, DHCP is coming from the Freifunk gateway.

Comment: I don’t know the specifics on that firmware, but limiting the number of associated clients is definitely possible. On OpenWrt, it’s a “[common option](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/wireless#common.options1)” (`maxassoc`).

Answer (score 2):

Limit your DHCP pool to 20 clients.  Others may try to connect, but they won't get an IP or have internet access, so they'll leave.  It's not great, but it's the best I've been able to come up with.